# Replacing doorbell transformer attached to electrical panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, nest, transformer, doorbell

I've been pulling my hair out trying to find my current doorbell transformer in order to upgrade it for a nest doorbell. I believe to have found it attached to my electrical panel after taking the cover off, but seemingly inside of the wall.

[image: Electrical panel]

[image: Transformer?]

I believe this is the doorbell transformer but I'm not 100%. I see that it is wired to the same circuit breaker which does power the existing doorbell, and it looks like a transformer but I cannot get the greatest view.
Is this definitely the doorbell transformer and is there an easier way to access it without cutting the wall?

Comment: While you're in there, figure out why there's a white wire attached to a circuit breaker.  Inspectors don't like to see that because the latest rules require colored tape at both ends.

Comment: what Robert said, but gray wires also,  and also taping is not allowed for conduit runs.

Comment: I agree, current code requires gray wires to be reidentified, but not sure how many inspectors would notice it.  I'm more concerned about the transformer being installed with black neutral wires (not allowed smaller than 4 ga).  The wire going to the breaker looks like it could be 18 ga or smaller and the breaker is rated 15 A.

Comment: @RobertChapin the rating is 15 amps. Should I also replace those wires with thicker guage?

Comment: Yes I found the link to the full-size photo while editing my previous comment.  Any circuit conductor on a 15 A breaker must be 14 ga or larger.  Ideally, get some black and white THHN for this little project.  You've also got some issues on the grounding bar where it looks like there are 6 individual wires under a single screw in two places.  These screws are typically rated for 1 to 3 wires.  And that medium stranded wire with the white insulation... it's NEUTRAL and should never be attached to the ground bar.

Comment: But also possible that neutral wire was repurposed for ground at the other end.  I'd leave that one alone for now.

Comment: @RobertChapin will do, thank you!

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to upgrade the transformer?  Oftentimes there's nothing wrong with the transformer, and the real problem is that a 2-wire doorbell connection is not working, becasue the chime is too high-resistance to allow the Nest to leak power through it. In that case, the fix is a bypass capacitor in parallel with the chime, not a transformer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I receive the error on the nest for a low voltage transformer, however it does seem possible that this would lead to the same error. I did get a new chime as well, I can try hooking that up and seeing if that would fix it as well. I have a multimeter, would I be able to test to see if the resistance is indeed the problem with it?

Comment: @EricTercasio You could wire both chimes in parallel, which will reduce resistance across them.  Modern electronic chimes are so efficient that they are often high impedance. You could also try paralleling in a "dummy load" capacitor, first one that comes to mind is the LUT-MLC which is a consumer product.

Comment: @RobertChapin it's a ul listed device wiring, just like the 18 awg wires in a lamp connected to a 15 amp breaker. And it's undoubtedly not user changable wiring.

Answer (score 2):

In all probably, it is the transformer and is the only device fed from the breaker. The drywall was added after the transformer was installed so you'll have to remove part of the wall to get to it. Then frame a small access panel so you can gt to your new transformer in the future. You'll need to turn that breaker off to remove the transformer.

Comment: Best way to be sure is to turn off the breaker and see if your doorbell still works.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Hi there. The OP does state that the tx is wired to the same breaker that does power the existing doorbell.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

It does look like the Transformer.

Unfortunately the only way to access it, would be to cut the dry wall.

Be careful not to cut wires, use a utility knife with adjusted depth to the thickness of the dry wall.

Comment: @ruskes  Why do you keep changing your "name"?

Comment: @JACK it is not me, there is a bug in the system, trying to solve, after joining woodworking, my profile here got corrupt, lost my original log in and have wired messages and points. Now stuck with user12622

Comment: I too have had login problems. Every time I open the site, it want's to do a password recovery.  I try that and never get the email.  But oddly enough, when I click on my G icon (for George) I get in no problem, and can interact as usual. It's annoying, but I have no idea who to contact to resolve the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I have been trying to use this https://diy.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: There is a Moderator that responds on https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/